# How to display a screen for 3 seconds, then switch to next screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to show a picture for 3 seconds so it feels like a loading screen. After that the app "starts" and the user can see the screen below.

[After "loading" screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvktX.jpg)

Do I need another storyboard? And if so, how can I connect them so that the second one starts after 3 seconds?

Comment: create newVC, set as start point of app, add timer for 3 sec after change your rootViewController, simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){ // change your delay here
      // redirect to next vc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) { 
    // show up your view controller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new view controller and set it as initial view controller,
then add the below code in viewDidLoad - swift4

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0){
 let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondviewcontroller") as! secondviewcontroller
            self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } 
}
```